# How to use `module load program/1.1` within a bash script?

Tags: shell-script, centos

Using CentOS 7.x, the correct way for users to "load" software to execute programs is to run via the command line:

```
module load program/1.1
```

What is the correct way to run this command via a bash script (e.g. to submit jobs to a computational cluster, etc.)? One could do

```
source module load program/1.1
```

What are the other options?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36728686/1707865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell script is just a list of commands to run, pretty much just as if you'd typed them at the command line. So the correct way is:

```
module load program/1.1
```

... just like you'd run at the command line. Note that if that gives a command not found, you probably need to source in `$MODULESHOME/init/<shell>` (which sets up the `module` command).

The `module` command is actually a shell function, that's how its able to manipulate your current shell's environment.

`source` does something different: it essentially copies & pastes the sourced script into yours. So if the source script defines functions, you can call them. If it set variables, even non-exported ones, you can see them.

Now, if you want to write a script that loads a bunch of modules for use in your interactive shell, then *from your interactive shell* you need to source *your script*, but not `module`. The [modules FAQ](https://sourceforge.net/p/modules/wiki/FAQ/#i-put-the-module-command-in-a-script-and-i-run-the-script-it-doesnt-change-my-environment) explains this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and eventually realized I needed the correct shebang and call function. So for future users, in three steps:

1) use `#!/bin/bash` as your shebang

2) add `module load program/1.1` to your script

3) run the script with `./yourscript.sh` or `bash yourscript.sh` but NOT `sh yourscript.sh` as this won't work